Javascript window.open does not open to the size I pass in
We have a security screen that opens a popup dialog box using a new custom script showWin that I wrote.
The security screen:
Private Sub SecCheck()
    Dim sScreenName As String = String.Format("{0}", Request("SCREEN"))
    Dim memb As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)

    If Roles.IsUserInRole(memb.UserName, sScreenName) Then
        Dim params As String = String.Format("{0}", Request("PARAMS"))
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(params) Then
            params = String.Format("?{0}", Request("PARAMS").Replace("$", "&"))
        End If
        Dim size As Size = ClaimsInfo.SecurityDB.GetScreenSize(sScreenName)
        ' Derive Java String
        Dim target As String = String.Format("frm{0}.aspx", sScreenName)
        Dim link As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", target, params)
        Dim height As String = CStr(size.Height)
        Dim width As String = CStr(size.Width)
        Dim parent As String = "self" ' Session("IFrame")
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parent)) Then
            parent = "_blank"
        End If
        Dim js As String = String.Format("showWin('{0}', {1}, {2}, 1, '{3}', '{4}');self.close();", link, width, height, target, parent)
        imgSec1.Attributes.Add("onLoad", js)
    End If
End Sub

I have placed a breakpoint where js is defined above, and I can see that the text being sent is:

showWin('frmHEIPayment.aspx', 886, 505, 1, 'frmHEIPayment.aspx', 'self');self.close();

Every time I call it, the dialog opens full screen. I've even edited the JavaScript command line above to use the sizes 200 and 200, but the dialog still opens the full size.
The JavaScript for showWin is below:
function showWin(link, width, height, type, target, sParent) {
    width = width || 400;
    height = height || 200;
    var features =
        'width:' + width + 'px,' +
        'height:' + height + 'px,' +
        'toolbar=no,' +
        'location=no,' +
        'menubar=no,' +
        'resizable=yes,' +
        'scrollbars=yes';
    target = target || "_blank";
    var childWindow = window.open(link, target, features);
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            return false;
            break;
        case 1:
            __doPostBack();
            sParent = sParent || "self";
            childWindow.opener.location = sParent;
            break;
        case 2:
            CloseDialogSessionExpired(window, 2)
            return false;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}

Also, showWin does not close the security screen with self.close() like what happens whenever I use our older jsOW (JavaScript Open Window) code.
I need to replace our older jsOW JavaScript that uses IE's window.showModalDialog:
function jsOW(link, width, height, type, sName) {
    var sFeature = "status:no;dialogWidth:" + width + "px;dialogHeight:" + height + "px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:no";
    if (type == "1") {
        var vVar = window.showModalDialog(link, window, sFeature);
        if (typeof (vVar) == 'boolean') {
            return vVar;
        } else {
            switch (vVar) {
                case 0:
                    return false;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    __doPostBack();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    CloseDialogSessionExpired(window, 2)
                    return false;
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

It displays the form with the correct size, but it only works in IE or Edge in Compatibility Mode.
How do I get this JavaScript to work?

MDN shows that window.showModalDialog() has been removed from Chrome and Firefox. I'd advise you to use its replacement, .

@mykaf that's why I am writing the newer script. This old website still uses showModalDialog.

The syntax does not use a ":" but you are to use a "="
eg;
window.open('mychild.aspx', 'childWindow', 'width=800px, height=400, top=200, left=200')

Hence try this:
         var features =
             'width=' + width + 'px,' +
             'height=' + height + 'px,' +
             'toolbar=no,' +
             'location=no,' +
             'menubar=no,' +
             'resizable=yes,' +
             'scrollbars=yes';

And you as a general rule don't have to supply the 'px' part. And you can add to above top=200, left=200 if you want to move the window down from upper left.
Note that for security reasons, quite a few browsers now don't hide the URL.
Also, as per my other comments, keep in mind that window.open() can be used, and such popups will not be blocked WHEN the code running is a result of user button click. For injected script, or even existing script (say to run on page load), then the popup blockers will block such windows. So, keep this "concept" of user code in the browser - popups should and can work just fine as long as the code running was triggered by an actual user button click.

OMG, a typo. My eyes are getting bad. I never noticed that. Thank you! Also, their website uses popups extensively. It is used by the employees of companies that purchase their products, and part of the training is showing them how to allow popups for the site. I still have not found a way to get the Main page to refresh when the Invoice page is open, but it will update as soon as it closes. I am eager to try this when we get back to work on Friday. Happy Thanksgiving, Albert! :)

That fixed the window sizing issue. I still can't get an item selected on the popup form to update the calling form until the popup form is closed. The older window.showModalDialog refreshes the calling page, whereas the current window.open method opens the refreshed page in a new tab.

One needs to look at the existing refresh code and how did it work? I don't have your code, so either as you selected items in the 2nd window, some kind of update to the database or some JavaScript was running to get the row id. Then when you hit the button to close the window (or some button to update), then the ID list is either passed back to the calling window, or that the calling window simply then did a refresh of the browser (a __DoPostBack() as js can do that. So, the fact of using showModalDialog is not how and why the window refreshed, but only that such code allowed refresh to run
